# How to get number Reverse using while loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get reverse of the number using while loop?

- Input:  number : 452833861
- Expected output : 168338254

I tried using reverse function

```
select reverse('452833861') reversno
```

using reverse works, but I need to implement it using a while loop.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the `REVERSE` function is not acceptable to you, assuming this is not a homework question?

Comment: Also: please show us your **current effort so far** - we'll help, but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
drop table #test
create table #test (id varchar(50))

insert into #test values ('452833861')

declare @i int = 0
declare @j int = (select len(id) from #test)

while (@i < @j)
BEGIN
select SUBSTRING(id,@j,1) from #test
set @j=@j-1
END
```